# How come I can't make a Material AppBar a separate class?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to separate the code for my app bar in my `Scaffold` widget into a separate class.

I wrote this (which compiles but doesn't correctly display):

```
    class MyAppBar extends AppBar {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AppBar(
      title: const Text('Sample Code'),
      actions: <Widget>[
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
          tooltip: 'Navigation menu',
          onPressed: null,
        ),
        IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.search),
          tooltip: 'Search',
          onPressed: null,
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class MyScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyScaffoldState createState() => _MyScaffoldState();
}

class _MyScaffoldState extends State<MyScaffold> {
  bool pressed = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: MyAppBar(),
```

What it displays:
[image]

While this code compiles and correctly displays the AppBar:

```
class MyScaffold extends StatefulWidget {
  _MyScaffoldState createState() => _MyScaffoldState();
}

class _MyScaffoldState extends State<MyScaffold> {
  bool pressed = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Sample Code'),
        actions: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
            tooltip: 'Navigation menu',
            onPressed: null,
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.search),
            tooltip: 'Search',
            onPressed: null,
          ),
        ],
      ),
```

which looks like this:
[image]

Can anyone help me with what's going on?

Comment: Do you get any error in the logs? I don't see a reason for the second code to not work.

Comment: As I mentioned, the second code does work correctly. I want to style my code like the first code block i show, but it is not displaying correctly (and there are no errors in the logs)

Comment: Can you send me the code in your main.dart file so that I can try to reproduce in local? You can use https://gist.github.com/ or a similar tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer here: [Handling the app bar separately](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51687194/handling-the-app-bar-separately)

I needed `class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget` to be `class MyAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget`